# Kentico - Selector to get the value of field of page type

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I need to use a selector that can help me get the value of a field of the page type I have added in the content tree.

For example: If I add a page type CMS.News in content tree and set the value of the "Title" field to be "test". So which selector should I use to get the value "test" of the field "Title"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you said selector what would you mean exactly? I think that a selector is a form control - a control that let you fill a field of page type in Pages application and form tab. For example, I have userID, an integer field, in my page type. I should use 'user selector' as form control for this field and this one will let me choose the user and get back his ID in my field. If you wish to get the value of your field in you site you will not need a selector.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest will be to use simple **Drop-down list** control and use Macro expression or SQL query (depends on if you want to retrieve custom field). I will assume that you need custom field, so you can try something like this:

```
Documents.WithAllData.Columns("Title").Where("ClassName='CMS.News'")#
```

where *Item transformation* and *Value column* fields contains field name that you need: `{% Title %}`